# TrueZip unable to extract file from archive

Tags: java, truezip

I am creating a java app that will extract the embedded thumbnail inside of a Powerpoint (PPTX) document. Since pptx files are zip archives, I am trying to use TrueZip to get the thumbnail found inside of the archive. Unfortunately whenever I try running my application it throws an IOException stating that the file is missing `C:\Users\test-user\Desktop\DocumentsTest\Hello.pptx\docProps\thumbnail.jpeg (missing file)`

Below is the code I use to get the thumbnail:

```
public Boolean GetThumbPPTX(String inFile, String outFile)
{
    try 
    {
        TFile srcFile = new TFile(inFile, "docProps\\thumbnail.jpeg");
        TFile dstFile = new TFile(outFile);

        if(dstFile.exists())
            dstFile.delete();

        srcFile.toNonArchiveFile().cp_rp(dstFile);

        return dstFile.exists();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DocumentThumbGenerator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Where `inFile` is the absolute path of the pptx file and `outFile` is the path that the thumbnail will be copied to. I can verify that the archive does have a thumbnail inside of it at the same exact path.

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer. It seems I did not have the Zip driver configured correctly. I added this to my class constructor and it all works now:

```
TConfig.get().setArchiveDetector(new TArchiveDetector(
            TArchiveDetector.NULL,
            new Object[][] {                
                { "zip|pptx", new ZipDriver(IOPoolLocator.SINGLETON)},
            }));
```